# recursive component communication in vuejs 2.0

Tags: javascript, recursion, vue.js, vuejs2

Lets say component name is "customComponent"

and its usage example:

```
<custom-component class='parent'>
  <div v-if='someTruthyCondition'>
    <custom-component class='child'></custom-component>
  </div>
</custom-component>
```

Lets assume, the 'someTruthyCondition' is true util 3 components get generated and recursion stops.

I would like to know how to communicate between the child customComponent to parent customComponent in vue js?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work since your example feels like a code-smell, and I have not tried something like this. You could use events and whenever a child component is created you could emit an event to your parent:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events

In the example from the Vue.js docs they use this:

```
<button-counter v-on:increment="incrementTotal"></button-counter>
```

So the child components call this inside the `created` lifecycle hook:

```
this.$emit('increment')
```

Whenever you receive this event inside your parent, you could just increment a number and when it reaches 3 your stop your `v-for` loop.

```
<custom-component class='child'></custom-component>
```

Granted I have no idea if this will even work, but on the top of my head this is something I came up with.

Comment: Could you please provide me a fiddle.
I tried to write the code, but missing the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use functions as props in Vue.js. It’s not a common pattern
>   because, unlike with React, Vue.js has custom events for
>   child-to-parent communication. But for cases like this one it really
>   comes in handy.
>
> Unlike emitting events at each level, this is much simpler and
>   performant since we only need to pass down the same reference to the
>   function.

Check [this](https://alligator.io/vuejs/communicating-recursive-components/) out.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think something like this may help you.

main.js:

```
window.Event = new Vue();
```

Parent element:

```
mounted () {
    Event.$on('recursion', () => {
        this.recursion++;
    })
}
```

Child elements:

```
created () {
    Event.$emit('recursion');
}
```

Comment: unable to figure out what you have mentioned. Fiddle would be helpful

Comment: @NitinKumar Look up "Vue.JS Event Bus"

Answer (score 0):

Use `v-on="$listeners"` to recursive child to trigger the event to parent.

When you attach any any event listener to first call of a component, then this way you can attach to all recursive call components.

```
<custom-component class='parent' @click="doSomething()">
  <div v-if='someTruthyCondition'>
    <custom-component class='child' v-on="$listeners"></custom-component>
  </div>
</custom-component>
```

Now in your component where you are consuming it, there will be `doSomething` method - and it will get triggered to any of the recursive child